# Why jquery toggleClass() only works in even siblings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have DOM like this in a Rails app:

```
<div class="post_info">
  <div class="col">
    <i class="post_comments">icon</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_body">
  <ul>
    <li>Many comments.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My target is hide and show `'.comments_body'` element right below the `'.post_comment'` icon which I clicked.

I've tried this:

**css**

```
.comments_body {
   display: none;
 }

.active {
   display: block;
 }
```

What I was trying to is target the icon's 'grandparent's next sibling', means the `comments_body` relating to this icon, then toggle it's `display` style.

**my jquery code:**

```
<script>
    $(".post_info").click(function(event) {
      $(event.target).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

But it turns out this only works on **even** `comments_body` like the `2nd ,4th ,6th ,8th`. 
I checked dev tool, when I click on odd icon, the event wasn't be triggered.

How to solve this? Or is there better way to achieve this effect?

**Update:**

I tried the answers below but still not work. [I put the page's github address here](https://github.com/gitCavendish/MiMic-T/blob/debugging/app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb). Since it's a Rails app, you might need to clone it to local and try it. If so, run [seed](https://github.com/gitCavendish/MiMic-T/blob/master/db/seeds.rb) to generate fake data. Thanks!

Comment: It will be easier to solve if you can give a JSFiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to remove the `:` from this:

```
.comments_body: { /* <==== Remove that : */
  display: none;
}
```

Then, `this` within your event handler is the `.post_info` element, so you can use that instead of `$(e.target).parent().parent()` which is inherently fragile (both because a small change to your markup breaks it, and because if you click within the `.post_info` but outside the icon, it will be wrong — which I suspect is why you're seeing the inconsistent behavior).

```
$(".post_info").click(function(event) {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$(".post_info").click(function(event) {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.comments_body {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="post_info">
  <div class="col">
    <i class="post_comments">icon 1</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_body">
  <ul>
    <li>Many comments 1.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="post_info">
  <div class="col">
    <i class="post_comments">icon 2</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_body">
  <ul>
    <li>Many comments 2.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="post_info">
  <div class="col">
    <i class="post_comments">icon 3</i>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="comments_body">
  <ul>
    <li>Many comments 3.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Side note: You might consider using event delegation for that handler rather than hooking the event on each individual `.post_info`. That way, if you add and remove `.post_info` instances at runtime, the handler will keep working.

Presumably these are in some kind of container, so you'd use:

```
$("selector-for-the-container").on("click", ".post_info", function(event) {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#container").on("click", ".post_info", function(event) {
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});

// Works on #4 even though we add it later:
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#container").append(
    '<div class="post_info">' +
      '<div class="col">' +
        '<i class="post_comments">icon 4</i>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="comments_body">' +
      '<ul>' +
        '<li>Many comments 4.</li>' +
      '</ul>' +
    '</div>'
  );
}, 800);
```

```css
.comments_body {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="post_info">
    <div class="col">
      <i class="post_comments">icon 1</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comments_body">
    <ul>
      <li>Many comments 1.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="post_info">
    <div class="col">
      <i class="post_comments">icon 2</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comments_body">
    <ul>
      <li>Many comments 2.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="post_info">
    <div class="col">
      <i class="post_comments">icon 3</i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="comments_body">
    <ul>
      <li>Many comments 3.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Informative answer. Thanks! I've tried your answer, but still can't make odd elements work. That's weird it works only on some of them. I'll keep trying.

Comment: I assigned more specific id to elements, and fixed this with your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $(".post_info").click(function(event) {
   
          $(event.target).parent().parent().next().toggleClass('active');
        });
```

```css
    .comments_body {
       display: none;
     }

    .active {
       display: block !important;
     }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="post_info">
      <div class="col">
        <i class="post_comments">icon</i>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="comments_body">
      <ul>
          <li>Many comments.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post_info">
      <div class="col">
        <i class="post_comments">icon</i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comments_body">
      <ul>
        <li>Many comments.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="post_info">
      <div class="col">
        <i class="post_comments">icon</i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="comments_body">
      <ul>
        <li>Many comments.</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

I have made a example for you. It working fine. I dont see any problem in case of even odd selection. try making important your active element as

```
.active {
  display: block !important;
 }
```

if it still not creating desired result kindly let me know. I will put my code here. Cheers....

Comment: do you got other approach to do this. Kindly put your code.

Comment: @Shashank Harit. The code in snippet works well. Both yours and T.J's. But for some reason it goes wrong when used on my app. I 've put the github repo address in my question. If you were still interested, check it. Thank you .